# Clearing <input type='file' /> using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<input ng-readonly="true"  value="{{ myFile.name}}" >
<md-icon aria-label="upload"  class="zmdi zmdi-close normal-font"></md-icon>
```

I have to clear a selected file on clicking icon how can I achieve this using **ng-click**

Comment: can you be more brief about your question?

Comment: more brief... this is lacking some code around the controllers

Comment: input is not having a type="file"

Comment: Here I have selected file for uploading but I want to remove from uploading window using <md-icon> it will display like this  (myFileName     X) when I will click on Icon it should be clear

Comment: '<input type="file" file-model="myFile"  required   accept=".xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" style="padding: 28px;border:none;"  aria-label="IMPORT SITES"/>'. **code above that two lines**

Comment: @Rakeschand please try to solve

Comment: I have done it using in **controller.js** as follow   `$scope.closeFile=function(){ $scope.myFile='';
 }`

Comment: And **HTML FILE** as`<md-icon aria-label="upload"   class="zmdi zmdi-close normal-font" ng-click="closeFile()"></md-icon>`